# Convert painting to a 20/30 color photoshop document

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a very old painting. This painting has been scanned and needs to be cleaned. By cleaned I mean: I define a color set of about 20/30 individual colors, and each pixel of the color is assigned to the color that matches it the most.

There are currently color nuances, shadows, dirt, and so on on the picture, and what i would need is the same image "the modern way", with solid matte colors. (the color beeing the average of the current color of that area)

for example the background a light red, but based on illumination and so on its not the same red everywhere.. I define the kind of red i would like, and apply it to the whole backgroundpixels..

It could be done by hand, but It would cost too much, so i have to automate it somehow.. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at Posterize? ..though you'll probably find 30 levels is actually too fine.

Comment: this should work! thank you! can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posterize might do it...
Image > Adjustments > Posterize

It's very dependant on your initial colour palette & you'll find that using just a few levels gives the impression that you 'meant to do it'.

[image]

At 30 levels, it just starts to look like a poorly-compressed jpeg.

[image]